# Why is the normal form of an ind-Nat expression with a function type an elimination-of-a-function expression

Tags: normal-form, pie

In this question, I am talking about the language [Pie](https://github.com/the-little-typer/pie) described in the book [The Little Typer](https://thelittletyper.com/).

Consider the definition

```
(claim foo-or-bar (-> Nat Atom Atom))
(define foo-or-bar
  (λ (n) (ind-Nat n
           (λ (n) (-> Atom Atom))
           (λ (a) 'foo)
           (λ (n-1 result_n-1 a) 'bar))))
```

If I then type `foo-or-bar` on a separate line and execute, Pie outputs

```
(the (→ Nat Atom
       Atom)
  (λ (n x₁)
    ((ind-Nat n
        (λ (n₁)
          (→ Atom
            Atom))
        (λ (a)
          'foo)
        (λ (n-1 result_n-1 a)
          'bar))
      x₁)))
```

So, Pie says that the second code snippet is the *normal form* of `foo-or-bar`. It's pretty clear why

```
(λ (n x₁)
  ((ind-Nat n
     (λ (n₁)
       (→ Atom
         Atom))
     (λ (a)
       'foo)
     (λ (n-1 result_n-1 a)
       'bar))
    x₁))
```

is the *same* `(-> Nat Atom Atom)` as

```
(λ (n) (ind-Nat n
           (λ (n) (-> Atom Atom))
           (λ (a) 'foo)
           (λ (n-1 result_n-1 a) 'bar)))
```

It's by *The Final Second Commandment of lambda*, which says

> If `f` is a `(Pi ((y Y)) X)`, and `y` does not occur in `f`, then `f` is the same as `(lambda (y) (f y))`.

But The Little Typer say that the *normal form* of an expression is the most direct way of writing it. And, frankly, what I wrote in the definition of `foo-or-bar` seems more direct than what Pie says its normal form is. So, why is that the normal form? I remember the book said somewhere that if `f` is a neutral expression of a Pi type, then `(lambda (x) (f x)` is the normal form of `f`. This seems similar to the situation with `foo-or-bar` but not directly applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 questions here.

The first one is whether the situation is applicable. In fact it is! This is because $(\lambda (x\ y)\ f)$ is abbreviation for $(\lambda (x)\ (\lambda (y)\ f))$. So you apply that in the inner layer.

The second question is why $(\lambda (x)\ (f\ x))$ is more "direct" than $f$. This is because $\lambda$ is the only way to create a $\Pi$ type. Thus it would be more direct to explicitly convey this knowledge. Remember that "direct" doesn't mean short or concise. For example, 10000000000 is a much more direct way to write $10^{10}$ but it is much longer.

The Little Typer chose to use a more blurry definition. But in practice it is well-defined. Only when the type is $\mathbb N, A+B, \mathcal U$, should a neutral term of that type be normal.

Comment: I think I understand now. If `n` is a variable of type `Nat`, and thus a neutral expression, is `(ind-Nat n (λ (n) (-> Atom Atom)) (λ (a) 'foo) (λ (n-1 result_n-1 a) 'bar)))` a neutral expression? Yes, by the box "Neutral expressions" in ch. 8. What is its type? Its type is `(Pi ((a Atom)) Atom`. What is its normal form? Its normal form is `(lambda (a) ((ind-Nat n (λ (m) (-> Atom Atom)) (λ (a) 'foo) (λ (n-1 result_n-1 a) 'bar))) a)`. It's considered simpler and more direct because it's not neutral, instead it's a value, I would guess.

Comment: If `e` is a type and `G` is an expression which is a type whenever `e` is a type, and `f` is a variable of type `(Pi ((x e)) G)`, why is `(lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (f y)) x)) ` not the normal form of `(lambda (y) (f y))`? Because `(lambda (y) (f y))` is not a neutral expression.

Comment: Why can a neutral expression of one of the types `Nat`, `A+B` ,`U` be normal? I would guess that it can be normal because those three types have multiple constructors, so if the expression is neutral, then we don't know which constructor was used. But can a neutral expression of the type `Atom` be normal?

Comment: If I write `(the (-> (-> Atom Atom) (-> Atom Atom)) (λ (f) f))` in Pie, it outputs `(the (→ (→ Atom Atom) Atom Atom) (λ (f x₁) (f x₁)))`. I think this means that the type `Atom` should also be added to your list of three special types.

Comment: @CrabMan Quite. I forgot there is an `Atom` type. It is actually special because it is not defined by a universal property (i.e. it doesn't have an eliminator). So the definition of normal/neutral can bend a bit. For example you can consider an atom to be *neutral*. It doesn't break the theory.

Comment: What does it mean that a type is defined by a universal property? I know a little about universal properties in category theory, for example the universal property of product.

Comment: @CrabMan I explained that in the parentheses.

Comment: does having an eliminator have anything to do with the universal property in the category theoretic sense?

Comment: @CrabMan They are the same.